# how do I use stateless iterators and start from an index other than 1 at the same time

Tags: for-loop, lua, iterator

I love lua's for loops and it's encouragement of stateless iterators like `pairs`/`ipairs`, but I have no idea how to start from indexes other than 1 when using them.

Comment: Although you gave `pairs` and `ipairs` as examples, it's worth pointing out that `pairs` has no defined order because a table's keys have no defined order and `ipairs` must start at 1 (at least internally) because it is defined to iterate up to the first `nil` value of positive integer keys, which of course start at 1. The first several of such keys could be skipped in the results but it still has to start at 1 to determine where the first nil value occurs. If you write your own iterator, you'd have to decide how much like `ipairs` you want it to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While iterators is stateless, meaning they're not holding any state, there's still state of the loop. See manuals for the details on generic loop. You can set your own initial values your custom iterator:

```
local function iter(table, idx)
    idx = idx + 1
    local v = table[idx]
    if v then
        return idx, v
    end
end

local function start_at(table, idx) 
    return iter, table, idx-1
end

local values = {33,42,77,91}

for k,v in start_at(values, 3) do
    print(k,v)
end
```

Assuming `ipairs` implementation will never change, you can hack in like this:

```
local values = {33,42,77,91}

for k,v in ipairs(values), values, 3-1 do
    print(k,v)
end
```

This last example will use default iterator, returned by `ipairs`, while dropping other values in loop state, substituting it with altered initial values. Not to be actually used in your code, but it illustrates an idea.

Comment: I don't understand you're second example. What is the `3-1` isn't that just `2`. I have never seen for loops like that. can you link me to some official documentation that uses similar loops?

Comment: `3-1` is intentional, as that's the starting position (`3`) reduced by one (`-1`). `ipairs`' iterator (the way it currently works) increments first, then gets the value. Just writing `2` wouldn't differentiate between a starting position of 3 (when internally incrementing first) or a starting position of `2` (when incrementing after). And for the general form of `for` loop, look at "generic for statement" in the [reference manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.3.5).